# Difference between click listener with jQuery and Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i tried to add a smoothScroll animation on each button that has a .smoothScroll class.

so i did this:

```
// SmoothSCroll
var smoothScroll = document.querySelectorAll('.smoothScroll');
[].forEach.call(smoothScroll, function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function() {
        var offset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: offset - (window.innerHeight/2) + ($(this.hash).innerHeight()/2)   
        }, 400 ); 
        return false;
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jt2jo3pt/2/

I don't know if you noticed what happened, but there is a little flash when the click triggered ( the scrollbar goes down a little before smoothscrolling )

But when i tried with full Jquery like this:

```
$('.smoothScroll').click(function(e){
        var offset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: offset - (window.innerHeight/2) + ($(this.hash).innerHeight()/2)   
        }, 400 ); 
    return false;
});
```

I don't have this bubbling effect: https://jsfiddle.net/34w72v1v/

Do you have any idea what could cause this issue with querySelectorAll method?

I try to not use jQuery so i need to know what's happening to learn :)

Thanks for your time.

Comment: `$('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: offset - (window.innerHeight/2) + ($(this.hash).innerHeight()/2) }, 400 );` does not look like _I try to not use jQuery_.

Comment: Why would you try *not* to use jQuery? It's there to make things simpler and shorter. If it is already in the website, then not using it is a waste :)

Comment: It is just for learning purpose.

Comment: I don't see the effect you describe (Firefox). Both fiddles do the same thing (except for the style difference).

Comment: FWIW, `return false` has no special side-effect in `addEventListener` handlers.

Comment: It is a pretty fast effect, look at the scrollbar maybe you will see it, or is it only with mac (chrome and firefox tested) ?

Comment: I see what you're talking about in Chrome. Check out the answers below, they're spot on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to preventDefault() in javascript to stop the window moving to the *bookmark* anchor:

```
// SmoothSCroll
var smoothScroll = document.querySelectorAll('.smoothScroll');
[].forEach.call(smoothScroll, function (el) {
  el.addEventListener('click', function(el) {
      el.preventDefault();
        var offset = $(this.hash).offset().top;
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: offset - (window.innerHeight/2) + ($(this.hash).innerHeight()/2)   
        }, 400 ); 
  });
});
```

`return false` is just a shortcut used for jQuery events to trigger both `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()`.

https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/jt2jo3pt/4/

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer, i didn't know for the return false and i did try with preventDefault but i didn't prevent on the right call (i did on .call instead of the listerner.. awfull :D) Thanks again! (you were too fast, i can't accept the answer right know, i will asap :))

Answer (score 3):

It's because of the `return false`. In jQuery, returning false from an event handler prevents the default behaviour taking place. In a ([non-inline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29969155/difference-between-click-listener-with-jquery-and-javascript?#comment48058263_29969248)) JavaScript event handler, it does nothing. For more info, see [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/444991).

Since your trigger is a `<a href="#test" class="smoothScroll">Go to test</a>`, upon clicking it the non-jQuery version is taking you down to the `#test` element, but in jQuery it isn't (since the default behaviour is being cancelled)... hence the flash.

If you either don't return false in jQuery, or add `e.preventDefault()` in the JavaScript version, you'll notice you can control the flash.

https://jsfiddle.net/34w72v1v/1/
https://jsfiddle.net/jt2jo3pt/3/

Comment: Nitpick... Only in `addEventListener()` handlers does `return false;` do nothing. In "property bound" handlers, it triggers `e.preventDefault();`. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's pretty clear to me now :)